# Android Manifest Error, Cant create new project, Main Activity and Styles.xml not being created

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, manifest

Just after recent updates, When I went for a new Android project in Eclipse, I got an error in the manifest(android:theme="@style/AppTheme")

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme')

Also,

1. Src folder is empty, Main Activity not being created Automatically.
2. No styles.xml file.
3. No R.java file.

I have also installed the new software from: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and restarted Eclipse.

I have everything up-to-date in my SDK Manager.

Also, cant add New Activities in existing projects.

Plz give suggestions to solve the issue

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: screw eclipse. Use Android Studio. version 1 released today

Comment: @Nasir...Thanx for the update

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with your project setup.  If you go the project's properties and click on Android make sure you have the appropriate "Project build target" selected and your libraries have to right paths.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response.Project Build Target is accurately set to API Level 21. Still the problem persists.

Comment: Also, on choosing a new workspace, the console says:[2014-12-09 22:50:05 - DeviceMonitor] Sending Tracking request failed!

Comment: You can also try to add the support library.  That class might be included in there.  I actually just remove that style from the styles.xml that is generated and remove the theme off of the application in the manifest until I need to make it custom.

Answer (score 0):

About the first question, when you create a new android project, the step of create Activity, you have to choose "Empty Activity". I think it's a bug. hope that can help.

Comment: obviously I did that, i chose blank activity as usual. Anyways, there was the prob with the ADT update. I ignored it and shifted to Android Studio. Now eclipse is history.

Comment: I am now using Android Studio too.